# Removing "LIVE" from VideoJS player

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I'm using this script [link](https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.min.js), and by default, LIVE system is enabled, how can I disable this?

Print about what I'm saying: [link](http://prntscr.com/o2s2jr)

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @mitrik, can we see your code? what do you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean you have a live video and want the live display not to show, or you have a VOD video that is being interpreted as live?